How to reset the test-network to its "blank" state
I've been playing around with Hyperledger's fabric-operations-console and the test-network. It's been a while and I was really pleasantly surprised as to how easy it is to spin up a lab to use for development and prototyping. Kudos to all the team!
However, I'd like to reset the environment for a different lab and cannot find where test-network and operations-console are persisting data. Am I missing something obvious here?
It would be nice, since it is a lab environment, to just reset the thing to a blank state to experiment with other lab projects.
